# Json parsing using Codable swift

Tags: json, swift, codable

I am seeing below error in Json parsing

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "Session_id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"Session_id\", intValue: nil) (\"Session_id\"), with divergent representation sessionId, converted to session_id.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Here is my structure:

```
struct RegisterModel: Codable {
    let message: String
    let code: Int
    let sessionId: String
    let userID: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case message, code
        case sessionId = "Session_id"
        case userID = "user_id"
    }
}
```

Below is my json response:

```
{"message":"Success","code":200,"Session_id":"50cfa8a4-b12b-4225-bcd4-4b9c9f434a00","user_id":"18"}
```

Here is the code for decoding json data:

```
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    let preis = try decoder.decode(RegisterModel.self, from: data)
                    print(preis)
```

Can somebody please check and let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your model seems to be OK except `userID` type, which should be `String` instead of `Int`. Just tested and decoding was correct.

Comment: How are you doing the actual decoding, are you perhaps setting keyDecodingStrategy to convertFromSnakeCase?